# How to mask browser URL with GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I'm currently looking for masking GWT browser URL.

Currently, when I access to an application page, my browser URL looks like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/app/#!config/users
```

or:

```
http://localhost:8080/app/#!b/reports?7900
```

I'd like to mask URLs with some kind of encoding like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/app/#!config/sdsuwksp
```

For example [Vaadin Framework](https://vaadin.com/) do exactly the same ([Vaadin Demo](https://taskmob.demo.vaadin.com/projects/tYAHhtQS)), but I don't know how to obtain this in my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with a `com.mvp4g.client.history.PlaceService` override. By overriding `convertToken` and `tokenize` methods I'm able to mask the GWT browser URL.

```
public class MyPlaceService extends PlaceService {

@Override
protected void convertToken(String token) {
    super.convertToken(UrlTokenizer.decode(token));
}

@Override
public String tokenize(String eventName, String param) {
    
    return UrlTokenizer.encode(eventName, param);
}}
```

Finally, in my gwt.xml file I've added this lines to "replace" PlaceService class with my own class:

```
<replace-with class="com.comp.app.gwt.mvp4.myPlaceService">
    <when-type-is class="com.mvp4g.client.history.PlaceService" />
</replace-with>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your application the URL is already processed, probably based on `com.google.gwt.user.client.History.getToken()`.
So, if you run

```
String token = History.getToken();
String[] params = token.split("/");
```

you get, in your example, **!config** and **sdsuwksp**. I guess **!config** would identify the page and **sdsuwksp** would be some masked value. If this masked value translates to pages (like `http://localhost:8080/app/#!config/users`), I can only advise not to mask it - **URL page names should be readable for the sake of SEO and usability**.

However, there are cases where you need to identify some entity, but you don't want to publicly display its auto incremented ID. Let's say you have a database with files data and you don't want to display the the auto incremented ID on the URL. For example, Google Drive has these kind of links: `https://docs.google.com/document/d/1TZplxR3yFGyPcCuaLHKptoVnxL4jOsTEGWFdqMoIu8/edit`. To achieve this, I see at least 2 relatively easy solutions:

- Use an unique randomly generated ID. Add an extra field 'idTag' to
  the database table of the entity you want to mask and make sure it is
  unique and not null. This extra    field becomes also an identifier
  of the entity. You can generate    unique ID with
  `UUID.randomUUID().toString()`, for example. Then you    can create
  links like    `#!config/users/cd9467cb-064a-4427-987f-738051dc5f79`
  instead of    `#!config/users/34` (which, in case of auto increment,
  everyone with    the link would know there are least 34 users in the
  database).
- Alternatively, your #!config/**sdsuwksp** value could be an encrypted
  string, that you can than decrypt on every request to check the
  actual request. You could use [gwt-crypto](https://code.google.com/archive/p/gwt-crypto/wikis/Usage.wiki). TripleDES could be used on the client side.

Comment: This is a customer specific request, so SEO isn't important in this case. I solved it with a com.mvp4g.client.history.PlaceService override. By overriding convertToken and tokenize methods I'm able to mask the GWT browser URL.